# Maclaurin series not giving right answers when manually deriving?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, infinity

Apologies about any formatting issues, I am new.

I have to find the first four terms of the Maclaurin series for $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

So first I plug in: 1st term is 1

Then derive $$(1-x)^{-1} = (1-x)^{-2}$$

and keep going

and then 4th term I get as $$\frac{3(1-x)^{-3}}{3!}$$

The answer says there is no denominator? but I'm getting over 2?

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Just as a side note, the verb form of derivative is "differentiate" not "derive". You take some equations and theorems and you DERIVE another equation or theorem. You take a function and DIFFERENTIATE it to find its derivative.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I knew that. I'm just in a rush. Forgive me

Answer (score 2):

. The third derivative is $-2(1-x)^{-3}$ nd the 4th is hence $6(1-x)^{-4}$

Comment: Yeah but doesn't the 4th term have no denominator? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maclaurin+Series+of+f%28x%29%3D1%2F%281-x%29

Comment: Maybe you did a manipulation mistake in derivatives, I edited the answer.

Comment: Wow in Maclaurin form, the 2 cancelled out with the 2! in the denominator, and i differentiated the next term without the 2. thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nifty way to do this problem. Recall that, by the infinite geometric series formula,

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 +  ...$$

From here, you can figure out all of your derivatives.

$$f'(x) = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 +  ...$$

$$f''(x) = 2 + 6x + 12x^2 +  ...$$

$$f'''(x) = 6 + 24x + ...$$

Now, just remember the formula for a Maclaurin series (of four terms).

$$f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)x^2}{2!}+\frac{f'''(0)x^3}{3!}$$

$$f(0) = 1$$

$$f'(0) = 1$$

$$f''(0) = 2$$

$$f'''(0) = 6$$

Now, you can just plug in the values for the various derivatives of $f'$ and you should be good to go. You may notice that this function turns out to be the first four terms of the original function. You would be right.